# Children require access-token from parent (Node.JS, API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, access-token

I am trying to create a client for a public API and I currently have this issue. Clients request an access token and then can use that access token in future requests as authentication. So I currently have a Client object that handles requesting and maintaining this key. Now, however I am instantiating subobjects by ID: `new Page(1)` and in order to get the information I would introduce something like `page.requestInformation()`.

My question is, what is the best practice/structure/pattern for my subobjects (Pages, Documents) to request information from the server when they themselves don't know the access token that is required to access the information?

```
var client = new Client('appid', 'appsecret');

client.getAccessToken(function (token) {
  doc = new Document(1); // Create a new document for ID = 1
  doc.fetchInformation(function (information) {
    // I now have the information.
  });

  // Doc would make a request to https://api.com/documents/1
  // but it needs to know the access token.

  // Would I just let every 'Document' type know the token from now on?
  // I'm asking what is the best structure for this kind of thing?
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Only opened this post because I thought it might contain adult content ... parents permission stuff. Why wouldn't the first token be applicable for all requests?

Comment: The first token is applicable for all requests, but would I just let all the children know it?

Comment: To be honest I don't understand what you are trying to do at all, or even what you are asking. What does ...`let the children know` mean?